# NodeJS/Express/Mongodb - Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am trying to make a reusable Mongodb connection `Object` through a separate module. So what is my strategy is to create a config file within a config directory

(**server/config/db-connection.js**) -

```
var MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
var _db;

module.exports = {
    connectToServer: function( callback ) {
        MongoClient.connect( "mongodb://localhost:27017/articles", function( err, db ) {
            _db = db;
            return callback( err );
        });
    },
    getDb: function() {
        return _db;
    }
};
```

Later I have been trying to initialize database connection within my server.js file

(**server.js**) -

```
const mongoConfig = require('./server/config/db-connection');

mongoConfig.connectToServer(function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Within router file, I have been trying to insert my post to `users` collection through using the reusable connection object.

(**server/routes/admin.js/**) -

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const mongoConfig = require('../config/db-connection');

var articlesDB = mongoConfig.getDb();

router.post('/configure', (req, res, next) => {
    let super_admin_info = req.body;
    super_admin_info.role = 'superadmin';

    articlesDB.collection('users').insert(super_admin_info)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            res.send('Successfully saved super admin');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I get following error -

> Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Can you please figure out what is the issue within my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your db-connection.js file. Mongo's connect callback used to return the db object, but no longer does directly. Now, you must ask for the database object directly, like so:

```
db.db();
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. I tried `_db = db.db('articles');` as well.